# How can I share my android project configuration

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know how I can do to configurate my project.

I have several librairies but I hava also teammates and they're working on Mac, and Ubuntu, and they're install on different folder.

Comment: Is your project not in a source control repository? The actual structure of the project should be the same, regardless of platform

Comment: yeah, the librairies are developped by others developers on others source control too

Comment: OK, so the issue is the libraries rather than the project structure?

Comment: The issue are the librairies path in the `project.properties` file and  the `Build Path`

Comment: OK, I may be missing the issue here. The .project file should not be part of source control. The libraries can be where ever each developer feels comfortable with it since they should all have their own .project files . In theory you could use something like maven or ivy to mange the library dependencies

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, I was wondering if they're right about adding the project file in the source control.

Comment: Anything environment specific should not be in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project file shouldn't be in your source control. 
Take a look on maven, it might help you.